# Bootstrap responsive issue in Firefox

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <ul class="row">
        <li class="col-xs-4 hidden-xs"></li>
        <li class="col-xs-4"></li>
        <li class="js-top-experts col-xs-4 hidden-xs"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And when I resize window width of each of li's changes dynamically. At least in Chrome and IE.
But not in Firefox. The width is static instead.
How should I resolve this?

Comment: Okay, could you tell me what you're exactly trying to do? This seems like a weird piece of grid structure that sould be done with divs, but is instead made by using `ul` and `li`... I don't know if this works or not, you should provide a bootply so I could test it out and mess around with it a bit more. - Still, my suggestion would be to go on and leave the lists as they are, and use regular divs instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If this won't work, add bootply link.

```
<div class="container">
  <div  class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12">
    <ul>
        <li class="col-xs-4 hidden-xs"></li>
        <li class="col-xs-4"></li>
        <li class="js-top-experts col-xs-4 hidden-xs"></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```